# Spring making call through Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring

I'm trying to make Ajax call in my jsp to Spring controller but its not listening the request.
Here is my code

Ajax code in my JSP:

```
$.ajax({
    url : "reSendSecurityCode",
    data : {param : reSendSecurityCode, uid : $('#username').val()},            
    success : function(data) {
      //logic   
    },
    type : 'GET'
});
```

Code in my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "reSendSecurityCode", method = RequestMethod.GET)
     public @ResponseBody String reSendSecurityCd(@RequestParam("param") String param, 
     @RequestParam("uid") String uid,String msg, HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) {
     //inside logic
     return "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am quite sure you are missing the context path of your app. Try adding the absolute path "/" to your JS code and in your Controller

```
$.ajax({
    url : "/reSendSecurityCode",
    data : {param : reSendSecurityCode, uid : $('#username').val()},            
    success : function(data) {
      //logic   
    },
    type : 'GET'
});


@RequestMapping(value = "/reSendSecurityCode", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String reSendSecurityCd(@RequestParam("param") String param, @RequestParam("uid") String uid,String msg, HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) {
     //inside logic
     return "";
}
```

Comment: After adding `/` in both ajax and controller also not working.

Comment: are you using some context path? first thing you need to know is which URL you need to request

Answer (score 0):

Replace your url like below:

```
$.ajax({
    url : "<c:url value="/reSendSecurityCode"/>",
    data : {param : reSendSecurityCode, uid : $('#username').val()},            
    success : function(data) {
      //logic   
    },
    type : 'GET'
});
```

You need to add taglib declaration in your jsp.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

Comment: what is the need of `<c:url>` here?

Comment: JSTL is a collection of useful JSP tags which encapsulates core functionality common to many JSP applications. <c:url> is one of them which will provide context path inside your application url.